# How to get Embeddings and Context matrices from Word2Vec in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, word2vec, svd

I am trying to extract from my `Word2Vec` model the Word/Embeddings Matrix (the one that has as rows each word vector, for word as center word) and the Context Matrix (the one that has as rows each word vector, for word as context word).

I have tried using `model.wv.syn0` and/or `model.syn0` to get the Embeddings matrix and `model.wv.syn1` and/or `model.syn1` to get the Context matrix, but I always get the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'syn0'

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'syn0'

AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'syn1'

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'syn1'
```

My ultimate goal is to make the product of Embeddings Matrix and Transposed Word Matrix (W.Ct) to get a final matrix that has the similarity between 2 words in each entry. If anyone could help me get that Matrix, or both the Embeddings and Word Matrices, it would be really helpfull!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From the class name `KeyedVectors` in your error messages, it appears you're using the Gensim library. The attribute name `.syn0` was only used in older versions (and `syn1` only some modes of some objects) – so wherever you got the notion to try those attributes is likely an outdated or misapplied example.

Full details of accessing parts of the `KeyedVectors` objects (which hold the sets of word-vectors even in full trained `Word2Vec` models) are available in the project docs at:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html

If you've trained full `Word2Vec` model in a variable `w2v_model`, the word vectors will be in the `w2v_model.wv` attribute, as a `KeyedVectors`, with all the operations documented above. (If you've loaded just word-vetors from elsewhere, you might just have a plain `KeyedVectors`.) Let's say, you put the `KeyedVectors` into a variable called `kv` - either from a `Word2Vec`...

```
kv = w2v_model.wv
```

...or by loading from some other file in the right format...

```
kv = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(MY_FILENAME, binary=True)
```

Most users don't need to access the entire internal matrices, instead using calls like:

```
kv['apple']  # returns word-vector for apple
kv.similarity('apple', 'orange')  # returns cosine-sim between words
```

You can get the array of all word-vectors, via:

```
kv.vectors
```

Each row will be one word vector, in the order described by `kv.index_to_word`.

There's no existing structure that's already holding all pairwise similarity comparisons. You could try to create one – but note it will be impractically large for many typically-sized models.

For example, a model with 200,000 words would have 200,000x200,000 similarities between pairs of words, or 40 billion floating-point (4-byte) values. So precalculating the entire word-to-word similarity matrix would take 160GB of RAM.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one last question: I have been able to fix an issue in my code and can now use Syn1. I get a matrix of the same size as the kv.vectors one. Is it the context matrix I have written about above?

Comment: In Gensim, `syn1` is a variable only used in the (non-default & less-commonly-used) `hs=1, negative=0` hierarchical-softmax training mode. It's technically the "hidden-to-output-layer" neural-network weights, & the interpretation of each row depends on the huffman-coding of potential predicted-words. (Each row is *not* any one word or even averaged-context.) In the (default & more-common) negative-sampling mode (eg `negative=5, hs=0`), each row of `syn1neg` *is* associated with a single output word, in the same ordering as the `.vectors` (previously `syn0`) input-to-hidden weights.

Comment: Some researchers, most notably Mitra et al from Microsoft Research, have shown those output weights, in the negative-sampling case, can be usefully considered word-vectors as well – though as far as I can tell, that's not a common practice. See: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/dual-embedding-space-model-desm/